# going through categories and posts does not work as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this piece of code

```
<ul>
<?php 

$categories = get_categories('include=9,4,5,6,7,8,3&hide_empty=0'); 

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $option = '<li class="mainop"><a href="#">'.$category->name.'</a>';

    $args = array( 'category' => $category->cat_ID );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    if ( count($myposts) > 0) {
        $option .= '<ul>';

        foreach( $myposts as $post ) {  
            setup_postdata($post); 
            $option .= '<li><a href=" '.the_permalink().' "> '.the_title().' </a></li>';
        }   

        $option .= '</ul>';
    }

    $option .= '</li>';
    echo $option;
}
?>
</ul>
```

It is supposed to draw all categories in a Wordpress blog and for each category the titles of the child posts.

However when running it is returning the following (html code):

```
<ul>
  <li class="mainop"><a href="#">Category</a></li>
  http://URL/?p=13Page13http://URL/?p=11Page 11http://URL/?p=9Page 9
  <li class="mainop"><a href="#">Category</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="  "> </a></li>
      <li><a href="  "> </a></li>
      <li><a href="  "> </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mainop"><a href="#">Category</a></li>
  <li class="mainop"><a href="#">Category</a></li>
</ul>
```

Do you have any idea why the titlea and the URLs are put in first place at the output and not where they are supposed to be?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the_permalink() and the_title() print out the link and title - they don't return the values as strings.  So when you call the functions, you are printing out the values into the page, and concatenating empty strings in their place to $option.

Comment: Actually they should be replaced by `get_post_permalink()` and `get_the_title()`